# Regex Matching using Matcher and Pattern

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to do regex on a number based on the below conditions, however its returning an empty string

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern



object clean extends App {

      val ALPHANUMERIC: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
      val SPECIALCHAR: Pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9\\-#\\.\\(\\)\\/%&\\s]")
      val LEADINGZEROES: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0]+(?!$)")
      val TRAILINGZEROES: Pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.0*$|(\\.\\d*?)0+$")

      def evaluate(codes: String): String = {

        var str2: String = codes.toString

        var text:Matcher = LEADINGZEROES.matcher(str2)
        str2 = text.replaceAll("")

        text = ALPHANUMERIC.matcher(str2)
        str2 = text.replaceAll("")

        text = SPECIALCHAR.matcher(str2)
        str2 = text.replaceAll("")

        text = TRAILINGZEROES.matcher(str2)
        str2 = text.replaceAll("")


      }

    }
```

the code is returning empty string for `LEADINGZEROES` match.

```
scala>  println("cleaned value :" + evaluate("0001234"))
cleaned value :
```

What change should I do to make the code work as I expect. Basically i am trying to remove leading/trailing zeroes and if the numbers has special characters/alphanumeric values than entire value should be returned null

Comment: if you want to remove leading zeros why don't you just cast it as integer

Comment: That will only solve half the problem, even i need to get rid of trailing zeroes

Answer (score 1):

Your `LEADINGZEROES` pattern is working correct as

```
val LEADINGZEROES: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0]+(?!$)")
println(LEADINGZEROES.matcher("0001234").replaceAll(""))
```

gives

```
//1234
```

But then there is a pattern matching

```
text = ALPHANUMERIC.matcher(str2)
```

which replaces all *alphanumeric* to *""* and this made `str` as *empty* ("")

As when you do

```
val ALPHANUMERIC: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
val LEADINGZEROES: Pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0]+(?!$)")
println(ALPHANUMERIC.matcher(LEADINGZEROES.matcher("0001234").replaceAll("")).replaceAll(""))
```

it will print *empty*

**Updated**

As you have commented

> > `if there is a code that is alphanumeric i want to make that value NULL
> >     but in case of leading or trailing zeroes its pure number, which should return me the value after removing zeroes
> >     but its also returning null for trailing and leading zeroes matches
> >     and also how can I skip a match , suppose i want the regex to not match the number 0999 for trimming leading zeroes`

You can write your evaluate function and regexes as below

```
val LEADINGTRAILINGZEROES = """(0*)(\d{4})(0*)""".r
val ALPHANUMERIC = """[a-zA-Z]""".r

def evaluate(codes: String): String = {
  val LEADINGTRAILINGZEROES(first, second, third) = if(ALPHANUMERIC.findAllIn(codes).length != 0) "0010" else codes
  if(second.equalsIgnoreCase("0010")) "NULL" else second
}
```

which should give you

```
println("cleaned value : " + evaluate("000123400"))
//    cleaned value : 1234
println("alphanumeric : " + evaluate("0001A234"))
//    alphanumeric : NULL
println("skipping : " + evaluate("0999"))
//    skipping : 0999
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: how can i avoid it to become null

Comment: what are you trying to do with alphanumeric?

Comment: if there is a code that is alphanumeric i want to make that value NULL.

Comment: but in case of leading or trailing zeroes its pure number, which should return me the value after removing zeroes

Comment: but its also returning null for trailing and leading zeroes matches

Comment: and also how can I skip a match , suppose i want the regex to not match the number 0999 for trimming leading zeroes